# Supabase: How to fetch two non related tables in a single query?

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

I have three Tables pingers, note_pings and link_pings. The Table structure are as follows:

```
Table pingers {
  id int PK
  user_id uuid
  username Text
}

Table note_pings {
  id int
  sender_user_id uuid //FK & PK
  receiver_user_id uuid //FK & PK
  ping_type Text
  content Text
  created_on Timestamp
}

Table link_pings {
  id int
  sender_user_id uuid //FK & PK
  receiver_user_id uuid //FK & PK
  ping_type Text
  content Text
  created_on Timestamp
}

Ref: "pingers"."user_id" < "link_pings"."sender_user_id"

Ref: "pingers"."user_id" < "link_pings"."receiver_user_id"

Ref: "pingers"."user_id" < "note_pings"."sender_user_id"

Ref: "pingers"."user_id" < "note_pings"."receiver_user_id"
```

In Supabase I want to fetch both note_pings and link_pings in a single query.
Current code:

```
  Future<void> fetchAllPings() async {
    try {
      final data = await supabase
          .from('note_pings')
          .select(
            '*, senderMetadata:sender_user_id!inner(first_name), link_pings(*,senderMetadata:sender_user_id!inner(first_name))',
          )
          .eq(
            'receiver_user_id',
            currentUuid,
          );

      print(data);
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I'm encountering the following error: "Could not find a relationship between 'note_pings' and 'link_pings' in the schema cache." It seems that Supabase is unable to automatically recognize the relationship between these tables.

Additionally, I've noticed that if there are two foreign keys in a single table pointing towards a single table, the query fails. Is there a workaround for this issue? Thank you for your assistance.